# ScrollView with embedded StackView issue

Tags: xcode, constraints, scrollview, stackview

I have a `scrollView` with a `stackView` placed in it. The `scrollView` is constrained to the `rootview`. The stack view will show a xib view.

The xib views are all different lengths. 
The xib views are labeled `simpleVC0` and `simpleVC1`. The length of the `simpleVC0`is 2500  and the length of `simpleVC1` is 1000.

My problem is that when the xib views are presented in the stack view the length of the `scrollView` does not change to the length of the presented xib view. 
It is like the xib view is presented but the scroll view is locked at a specific length.

Here is `simpleVC0` xib view. followed by it when run. When I try to scroll it doesn't allow me to scroll to the bottom of the xib view. it seems to cut the xib view off at a certain length. 
Am right in saying that this is possibly an issue that may have to be resolved in code? or can it it solved souled by the constraints. 
I have tried auto layout constraints however they have not worked.

[image]

[image]
[image: An example of how far down i can scroll (note the xib view is cut off as it only shows a certain amount of green.)]
[image]

[image]

I have constrained the `scrollView` to the `rootview` on all four sides.
When the root view is loaded the xibs are established using the following code:

```
    //Different subViews for ingredients and steps
    if counter == 0 {
        simpleViewX = SimpleVC0().view
        simpleViewY = SimpleVC1().view
        stack.addArrangedSubview(simpleViewX)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(simpleViewY)
    }
```

The views are the hidden shown by changing the value of the segmented view controller. Shown below:

```
    @IBAction func tabselected(_ sender: Any) {
    switch (sender as AnyObject).selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        simpleViewY.isHidden = true
        simpleViewX.isHidden = false

        break
    case 1:
        simpleViewX.isHidden = true
        simpleViewY.isHidden = false

        break
    case 2:
        //calledvideo in array is the value of the counter.
        calledVideo = vids[counter]
        geturl()
        break
    default:
        break
    }
    }
```

Comment: Show how are you loading the xib content.

Comment: @DonMag just updated it there to show how xibs are called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a `UIStackView` with a `UIScrollView` you need to allow the stack view to expand its height based on its content.

When laying it out in storyboard, give the stack view a height constraint (to satisfy IB's requirements), but give that height constraint a low Priority.

Then, when adding arranged subviews, the stack view will grow vertically.

Here's a complete example, based on the images you've shown: https://github.com/DonMag/XIBsInScrollView

Comment: Thank you my man, you dont understand how much you have helped. Took me two days playing with it, no joke. Thanks again appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the contentSize property of your scrollView in the code. I don’t know how to deal with it with storyboards, but you can make an outlet of your scrollView and calculate the new height each times it changes (each time you add something or remove something in it)

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:yourNewW, height:yourNewH)
```

Comment: Better to use auto-layout and constraints.

Comment: Honestly I gave up mixing scrollView with autolayout, it’s been a nightmare of bugs every-time when I tried. From my point of view it’s much more precise and effective to compute old plain coordinates when working with content of a scrollview